# Grund und Boden

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ich möchte mir gern Klarheit über den Ausdruck *"Grund und Boden"* verschaffen.
Warum werden beide Begriffe in Texten über Grundeigentum und in vielen Redewendungen IMMER paarweise (mit der Konjunktion dazwischen) verwendet? Z.B.

*"Eigentümer von Grund und Boden unterliegen dem Steuergesetz so-und-so"*

*"Geh runter von meinem Grund und Boden"*

Würde da nicht einfach EIN EINZIGES Wort genügen, also, ENTWEDER Grund ODER Boden, da sie praktisch dasselbe bedeuten?

Comment: Ich bin nicht ganz sicher, nach was du suchst. Hast du Deutsch als Fremdsprache gelernt und verstehst die Bedeutung von "Grund und Boden" nicht oder bist du etymologisch an diesem Ausdruck interessiert?

Comment: Ich bin kein Deutschmuttersprachler, sondern Fremdsprachler, und für mich gibt es noch viel, viel zu lernen... :-)
Daher meine o.g. Frage.

Comment: Die Wikipedia auch sagt, dass "Grund und Boden" ein Beispiel für das Hendiadyoin sei.  https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendiadyoin

Comment: Vielen Dank, Satish Vasan!

Comment: https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~sich%20in%20Grund%20und%20Boden%20sch%C3%A4men&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou

Answer (score 3):

Man könnte denken das wäre eine Tautologie, aber "Grund und Boden" ist ein sehr alter *juristischer Begriff* und Rechtsprechung ist ein kompliziertes Ding:

Der *Grund* ist ganz einfach die Fläche, die ein Grundstück ausmacht ("10a Grund").

Unter "Grund und Boden" versteht die Rechtsprechung mehr: Nämlich alles, was darüber hinaus fest mit dem Grundstück verbunden ist - z.B. Bäume und Pflanzen, die auf dem Grundstück wachsen, Landwirtschaftliche Erträge und alle Immobilien, die draufstehen.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Wie ich sehe, muß ich mein Verständnis beider Begriffe erweitern.

Ich habe Boden und Grund einfach als dasselbe aufgefasst: Also, die bloße Fläche, auf der wir stehen können, wie die Komposita bzw. Ausdrücke zum Ausdruck bringen:

Fußboden/am Boden zerstört/Dachboden
Grundstück/Grundmauer/u. erweitert: et. begründen

Aus der o.g. Antwort ersehe ich aber, Grund+Boden weit mehr ist als nur Boden oder nur Grund allein. Der Ausdruck veranschaulicht also einen viel größeren Umfang.

Comment: Hast du dafür eine Quelle? :) bzw woher kommt "10a Grund". Den letzten Absatz kann man - zumindest für Dtld - aus § 94 BGB ableiten.

Comment: Ohne dem vertieft nachgehen zu können: Zum 'Boden' gehört (u.a.) die Zusammensetzung des Erdreichs (sandig, tonig), der Nährstoffgehalt und vieles weitere. Im Boden sind jedoch auch (abbaubare) 'Bodenschätze' wie Kies, Sand u.ä., die dem Bergrecht unterliegenden (Kohle, Erze, Gold...) gehören nicht dazu. Der Grund(stück)eigentümer besitzt damit nicht nur die Fläche (den Grund, wie er im Grundbuch eingetragen ist), sondern auch den auf der Fläche vorhandenen Boden, den er rein theoretisch verkaufen könnte (Mutterboden), was bei Neubauten auf 'grüner Wiese' auch geschieht.

Comment: In der alten juristischen Sprache sind solche Doppelformen häufig: _nach Jahr und Tag, sich um Kopf und Kragen reden, Haus und Hof verlieren, mit Kind und Kegel_ usw. Bei https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php  findet man jeweils Erklärungen dazu. Für _Grund und Boden_ sind dort etliche weitere Verwendungen beschrieben: _sich in Grund und Boden schämen, die gegnerische Mannschaft in Grund und Boden spielen_ usw.